# How to code in notification mail a link to page with automatic login

Tags: email, login, solspace-friends

Is there a way to code links in notification mails (to a potential logged out user) in such a way that the user goes directly to the message page, without the login procedure?

(In my case, Solspace Friends module generates a notification link to a page only visible for logged in members.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Logmein http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/logmein. In my notification template:

```
{path="registreren/return/"}/{friends_message_id}/{friends_recipient_username}
```

In template 'return' I grab the username wrapped in a condition if they are logged out:

```
{if logged_out}
    {exp:logmein:now username="{segment_4}"}
{/if}

{redirect= '/vrienden/mijn_berichten/message/{segment_3}/'}
```

and lead the user (now logged in) further to the desired template where he/she can see the message.
Works like a charm.
Thanks for making this plugin!